# ORACLE (PL/SQL), create function that would add number to array

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql

I would like to create a function that would take an array and a number as paramaters, add that number to that list and return it.

Here's what I've made but it doesn't seem to work

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE numList IS VARRAY(100) OF NUMBER;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addNumToArray (v_var NUMBER, listOfNumbers IN OUT numList)
RETURN numList
IS
    v_count NUMBER:=listOfNumbers.COUNT;
BEGIN
    listOfNumbers :=numList();
    listOfNumbers.extend();
    listOfNumbers(v_count):= v_var;
RETURN listOfNumbers;
end;
```

When I call this function, it is always replacing the one number so the size is always one.

I tried to execute it like this but the result is always the last inserted number, in this case 17.

```
DECLARE
    ArrayNum numList := numList(10);
BEGIN
    ArrayNum:=addNumToArray(15,ArrayNum);
    ArrayNum:=addNumToArray(17,ArrayNum);
    FOR i in 1 .. ArrayNum.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ArrayNum(i) || ' ' || ArrayNum.COUNT);
    END LOOP ;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function does this:

```
listOfNumbers :=numList();
```

which means you start with an empty list each time the function is called, and don't retain the old values; you just always put the new value into the otherwise-empty list.

You need to get rid of that, and also increment the counter after extending:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addNumToArray (v_var NUMBER, listOfNumbers IN OUT numList)
RETURN numList
IS
    v_count NUMBER:=listOfNumbers.COUNT;
BEGIN
    listOfNumbers.extend();
    listOfNumbers(v_count + 1):= v_var;
    RETURN listOfNumbers;
end;
/
```

or without the counter variable, just using `listOfNumbers.COUNT` - which will be incremented automatically by the `extend()`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addNumToArray (v_var NUMBER, listOfNumbers IN OUT numList)
RETURN numList
IS
BEGIN
    listOfNumbers.extend();
    listOfNumbers(listOfNumbers.COUNT):= v_var;
    RETURN listOfNumbers;
end;
/
```

But as you have an `IN OUT` argument this can be a procedure instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE addNumToArray (v_var NUMBER, listOfNumbers IN OUT numList)
IS
BEGIN
    listOfNumbers.extend();
    listOfNumbers(listOfNumbers.COUNT):= v_var;
end;
/
```

which is then called as:

```
DECLARE
    ArrayNum numList := numList(10);
BEGIN
    addNumToArray(15,ArrayNum);
    addNumToArray(17,ArrayNum);
    FOR i in 1 .. ArrayNum.COUNT LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ArrayNum(i) || ' ' || ArrayNum.COUNT);
    END LOOP ;
end;
/
```

All three versions get the output:

```
10 3
15 3
17 3
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a5be9fecfd5faab547c0ab2d4bc7f7e2)